# php regex remove empty dive except one id

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have a code to remove all empty elements from php output:

```
    $original="";
    while($body != $original) {
    $original = $body;
    $body = preg_replace('%<(.*?)[^>]*>\\s*</\\1>%', '', $body);
    }
```

I want to remove all empty element except one empty div with id="maximenu"

How can I change the code above to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Regex is not the correct tool for parsing HTML instead you can use `DOMDocument`

Comment: why regex is not the correct tool for this?